# What does "live in a tower" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [Braveheart (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart), Queen Isabella meets prisoner William Wallace:

> Queen Isabella: Sir, I come to beg you to confess all and swear
> allegiance to the king that he might show you mercy.
>
> William Wallace: Will he show mercy to my country?
>
> Queen Isabella: Mercy is to die quickly, perhaps even **live in a tower**.

What does "live in a tower" mean?

I know what live in an/(one's) ivory tower means but this one look
different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think she means that he might live imprisoned in a tower for life, as an alternative to dying quickly.

It might be a reference to The Tower of London, a famous prison, where Queen Isabella had someone imprisoned:

[Wikipedia Tower of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London)
"...became the first woman imprisoned in the Tower of London after she refused Queen Isabella admittance to Leeds Castle...".